# How to updating number of displayed elements per page with a drop down list in ASP.NET core mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pagination, entity-framework-core, dropdown

This is the code of my controller action.Currently I'm hard coding the number of items being displayed which is 2. I want to select the number of items from dropdown so that when a user selects a number such as 10 then view will display ten items per page. Please someone help me as I'm new and not getting any solutions related to this and it's needed in my semester project. I'll be extremely thankful.

```
 public IActionResult Index(string sortOrder,int pageNumber=1,int pageSize=2)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSortOrder = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParam =String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder)? "name_desc":"";
        int ExcludeRecords = (pageSize * pageNumber) - pageSize;
        var Students = from b in _context.Students.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList()
                       select b;

        switch (sortOrder)
            {
               case "name_desc":
                 Students= Students.OrderByDescending(a => a.Name).ToList();
                   break;
               default:
                   Students = Students.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
                   break;
           }


        Students = Students.Skip(ExcludeRecords)
            .Take(pageSize);
        var result = new PagedResult<Student>
        {
            Data = Students.ToList(),
            TotalItems = _context.Students.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).Count(),
            PageNumber=pageNumber,
            PageSize = pageSize
        };
       
        return View(result);
    }
```

This is the pager code and I'm using cloudscribe Pagination:

```
<cs-pager cs-paging-pagenumber="(int)Model.PageNumber"
      cs-paging-totalitems="(int)Model.TotalItems"
      cs-paging-pagesize="Model.PageSize"
      cs-pagenumber-param="pagenumber"
      asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewBag.CurrentSortOrder"
      asp-controller=@ViewData["Controller"]
      asp-action=@ViewData["Action"]
      cs-pager-li-current-class="page-item active"
      cs-pager-li-other-class="page-item"
      cs-pager-li-non-active-class="page-item disabled"
      cs-pager-link-current-class="page-link"
      cs-pager-link-other-class="page-link">
```

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your problem? If it is solved, please [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979/710667), otherwise, please tell me your still existing problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `pageSize` parameter to pass to the action in `cs-pager`, save the pageSize value selected by dropdown each time, and bind it back to the data.

First use  `ViewBag.pageSize = pageSize;` to save the `pageSize` from view,

then in view  use this code  to get selected pageSize before:

```
   @{ 
        var selectedIndex = (int)ViewBag.pageSize;
    }
```

Last, add  `asp-route-pageSize="@selectedIndex"` in cs-pager.

Here is compelete code for your reference:

View:

```
@{ 
    var selectedIndex = (int)ViewBag.pageSize; //add this line
}

@model xxx

<h1>Index</h1>

<form action="/Controller/Action" method="POST">
    <select name="pageSize" asp-for="@selectedIndex"  onchange="javascript:this.form.submit()">
        <option>please choose a number</option>
        <option value=1>1</option>
        <option value=2>2</option>
        <option value=3>3</option>
        <option value=4>4</option>
        <option value=5>5</option>
        <option value=6>6</option>
        <option value=7>7</option>
        <option value=8>8</option>
        <option value=9>9</option>
    </select> 
</form>



<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Studentname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var a in Model.Students.Data)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@a.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<cs-pager cs-paging-pagenumber="(int)Model.PageNumber"
      cs-paging-totalitems="(int)Model.TotalItems"
      cs-paging-pagesize="Model.PageSize"
          cs-pagenumber-param="pagenumber"
          asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewBag.CurrentSortOrder"
          asp-controller="@ViewData["Controller"]"
          asp-action="ViewData["Action"]"  asp-route-pageSize="@selectedIndex"
          cs-pager-li-current-class="page-item active"
          cs-pager-li-other-class="page-item"
          cs-pager-li-non-active-class="page-item disabled"
          cs-pager-link-current-class="page-link"
          cs-pager-link-other-class="page-link"></cs-pager>
```

Action:

```
 public IActionResult Index(string sortOrder,int pageNumber=1,int pageSize=1)
    { 
        ViewBag.pageSize = pageSize;// add this line,it is the key point
        ViewBag.CurrentSortOrder = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParam =String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder)? "name_desc":"";
        int ExcludeRecords = (pageSize * pageNumber) - pageSize;
        var Students = from b in _context.Students.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList()
                       select b;

        switch (sortOrder)
            {
               case "name_desc":
                 Students= Students.OrderByDescending(a => a.Name).ToList();
                   break;
               default:
                   Students = Students.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
                   break;
           }


        Students = Students.Skip(ExcludeRecords)
            .Take(pageSize);
        var result = new PagedResult<Student>
        {
            Data = Students.ToList(),
            TotalItems = _context.Students.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).Count(),
            PageNumber=pageNumber,
            PageSize = pageSize
        };
       
        return View(result);
    }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]